# How to create sticky Social Media Tabs to the right of the website?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

How to create sticky Social Media Tabs to the right of the website?

See the below screenshot for how it stick at the right:

> [image]

Is there any Drupal module or plugin available?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Social media](https://drupal.org/project/socialmedia) module, it will display as block and then assign it to the proper region and AFAIK no module exist as such, you need to customize through CSS.

> The social media module helps integrate your website with social media
>   sites such as Twitter, Facebook and Google+. It provides an
>   centralized way of managing social media profile information and
>   plug-in widgets such as follow and share buttons.

if you are looking to share the posts then [Share Bar](https://drupal.org/project/sharebar) is the right choice for you.

> The Drupal Sharebar module lets you easily add a "floating" social
>   media submission bar on your website (like that found on Mashable)
>   that includes share buttons for the most popular social media websites
>   online such as Facebook, Twitter, and Google +1 Buttons.